# Rotating one image under another one

Tags: java, image, rotation, graphics2d

I am currently trying to rotate an image and then drawing an image on top which isn't rotating. But whenever I use:
`g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rot), (x+15), (y+15));`
every image I draw afterwards rotates as well. Is there any way I can rotate one image and not rotate the rest (gosh its really hard to explain).
Here's my paint method:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    move();
    if(bo.px==+1)rot--;
    if(bo.px==-1)rot++;
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rot), (x+15), (y+15));
    g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, null);//this should rotate
    g2d.drawImage(shine, x, y, null);//this shouldn't
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the original transform, rotate and draw the first image and then apply back the original transform before drawing the second image.

Try

```
AffineTransform originalTransform = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rot), (x+15), (y+15));
g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
g2d.setTransform(originalTransform);
g2d.drawImage(shine, x, y, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you draw the rotated image you need to perform the inverse rotation to bring things back to the original non-rotated state.

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    move();
    if(bo.px==+1)rot--;
    if(bo.px==-1)rot++;
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rot), (x+15), (y+15));
    g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, null);//this should rotate
    g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(rot), (x+15), (y+15)); // this resets the rotation!
    g2d.drawImage(shine, x, y, null);//this shouldn't
}
```

Comment: Probably simpler, cleaner and less error prone to do Bala's method of simply saving the original AffineTransform. 1+ to Bala.